# Generate/Get random queries for testing search engine performance

Tags: performance, list, search, random, search-engine

I have a search engine and I want to test its performance. I want a list of queries (not necessarily just words, they may/should contain multiple words and hopefully advanced queries like a*) that I can use it my search engine. As is the case with every search engine, it may contain duplicates.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get a [dictionary](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) and generate as many combinations as you want.